# How to design period time(business hours) in the SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have such a scene like this: In my system, there are some opening time for a food store. The business scene like this:

For my food store which named 'Pet food', it will be open from Tuesday to Friday, from 11 am to 2 pm.

**I want to know that how to better store these business hours.**

I use the Sql Server database, and the Entity Framework core.

I found that some guys suggest using the xml data type for the business hours in Sql Server. If I do this, **how do I use entity framework core to query the business hours and how display it on the html.**

I want to show the open business hours in the web. When someone get into this web store, if he add a access reservation that he will visit this store. Then the system will be check his appointment time is valid

Comment: Create a calendar table that holds the start and end business hours of each day. You can then use a custom SQL function or view to correctly query it.

Comment: This will be very cumbersome when querying data.I want to know whether there are some good solution for this case

Comment: Try adding a few examples of how you plan to use these hours, will help understanding better your requirements.

Comment: I have edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use Entity Framework's "Value Objects" feature.

This allows you to have the SQL representation e.g. a number for the day of the week 1 - 7, and a SQL TIME as the opening time and SQL TIME as the closing time composed back into a single object which says the opening hours.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects#important-characteristics-of-value-objects

Comment: I have the business hours like this:

Comment: I have the business hours like this:
store 1: 
         Opening time: From Monday to Thursday, From 2:00 am to 13:pm
Store 2:
         Opening time: From Wednesday to Friday, From 11:00 am to 13:pm(except holiday)
and so on. 
Did you mean that set a table for the business hours? and using the "Value Objects" to combination them in one field in code?

Comment: I suppose what I mean is Value Objects gives you the ability to have the best schema in SQL Server whilst still having an easy to use object in c#.

Perhaps share what have already for your SQL Schema so people can comment.